# Pull a file from android emulator/device programmatically

Tags: android

I am familiar with adb pull command. Is it possible to pull a file from android device/emulator and saving it in specified location in PC programmatically?

Comment: What do you mean programmatically? Which language-environment are you planning to use? Will the code run in your PC (can't you just launch a shell process and call adb pull?) or in the emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, on linux use system() to execute adb (perhaps by its full path) with the appropriate arguments.  OSX is probably something quite similar.

On windows... CreateProcess() but that returns before the child is finished, so you may have to spend some time wandering around MSDN to figure out the equivelent of system()